# APA 6 seems to be used, instead of APA 7, by biblatex-apa (providing three authors instead of using et al.)

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style, apa7

To start with, I am quite new to LaTeX coding. I used a standard `MasterDoctoralThesis` template. I encountered an issue, however, as also typified in an MWE:

I want to use the latest APA style: 7th ed. Using the `biblatex-apa` package. [Compared to Version 6](https://warren.libguides.com/APA7/6v7), Version 7 should provide the first author followed by "et al.", when there are three or more authors already, instead of the first written out in the case of > 3 and < 6 authors. However, in my case it seems to do the latter instead:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel} 
\documentclass[
11pt,
english]
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text \textcite{Zanoni_2006} some other text \parencite{callioni_2005, song_zipkin_1996}. 

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \textcite{callioni_2005} &  \\
        \textcite{song_zipkin_1996} & \\
        \textcite{Zanoni_2006} & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\textcite{callioni_2005} Some other text \parencite{Zanoni_2006}.

\end{document}
```

With my `example.bib`:

```
@article{song_zipkin_1996, 
    title={{MANAGING INVENTORY WITH THE PROSPECT OF OBSOLESCENCE}}, volume={44}, 
    DOI={10.1287/opre.44.1.215}, 
    number={1}, 
    journal={Operations Research}, 
    author={Song, J.-S. and Zipkin, P.H.}, 
    year={1996},
    pages={215–222}}
    
@article{callioni_2005, 
    title={Inventory-{Driven} {Costs}}, 
    journal={Harvard Business Review}, 
    author={Callioni, G. and de Montgros, X. and Slagmulder, R. and Van Wassenhove, L.N. and Wright, L.}, 
    volume = {83},
    number = {3},
    ISSN = {0017-8012},
    year={2005},
    pages={135-41, 150}}

@article{Zanoni_2006, 
    title={Cost performance and bullwhip effect in a hybrid manufacturing and remanufacturing system with different control policies}, 
    volume={44}, 
    DOI={10.1080/00207540600857375}, 
    number={18-19}, 
    journal={International Journal of Production Research}, 
    author={Zanoni, S. and Ferretti, I. and Tang, O.}, 
    year={2006},
    pages={3847-3862}}
```

It produces:

> Some text Zanoni, Ferretti, and Tang (2006) some other text (Callioni, de Montgros,
> Slagmulder, Van Wassenhove, & Wright, 2005; Song & Zipkin, 1996).

Instead of (the desired output):

> Some text Zanoni et al. (2006) some other text (Callioni et al., 2005; Greenwade, 1993; Song & Zipkin, 1996).

And in the table it also produces all authors yet again:

> Callioni, de Montgros,Slagmulder, Van Wassenhove, & Wright (2005) and Zanoni, Ferretti, and Tang (2006)

However, in the last part it shows it correctly (which is also the 6th edition version):

> Callioni et al. (2005) Some other text (Zanoni et al., 2006).

Might someone be able to suggest how I can ameliorate this, and obtain my desired (Version 7—compliant) output?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! Your example produces the correct output with `article` class, which leads me to believe that the problem is somewhere in your class file. Does it load `biblatex`, if so, it may be passing different values to the parameters that control this `mincitenames` and `maxcitenames`. Since that's not a freely available class, you may just want to comment out its loading of `biblatex` (which is probably what's going on.)

Comment: There are several versions of the dreaded `MastersDoctoralThesis` out there. In one of the newer versions that I found, the class does not load `biblatex`. I'm going to assume you use such a version, because you explicitly load `biblatex` in your preamble. If you get APA6 output from `biblatex-apa` the most likely explanation is that your `biblatex-apa` version is too old. Versions released before November 2019 implement APA6. You only get APA7 if your version is new enough. ...

Comment: @moewe I work in overleaf and started this project end 2018. I think it might indeed be outdated as when I remove the '\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa} it gives some errors again. I checked the main settings of Overleaf and it was indeed on 2018. When updated to 2019 (legacy) it solved the issue.

Comment: You may want to upgrade to the newest TeX Live Overleaf have to offer. TeX Live 2019 is about three years old now. Especially `biblatex-apa` can benefit from an update. There were some issues with very early versions of `biblatex-apa` v9.x.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by an outdated TeX Live version with an old `biblatex-apa` that was still on 6th edition APA style. Switching Overleaf to a newer TeX Live solved the issue.